# How to copy an entire row from one table to another in mysql with the second table having a modified field

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a project where I need to import many rows with over 200 fields from an old table into a new, but the id field needs to have a "5" prepended to it.

I'm using this SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO brinkoet_dev.property
SELECT liveprop.*
FROM brinkoet_live.property liveprop
WHERE listing_office='Brink';
```

but have no obvious way of being able to change an existing field's contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your new table rename the 'id' field to 'id_old'. In your new table, add an 'id' field at the end of this table. Then you can do the following:

```
INSERT INTO brinkoet_dev.property 
    SELECT liveprop.*, CONCAT(5, liveprop.id) 
    FROM brinkoet_live.property liveprop 
    WHERE listing_office='Brink';
```

After it's finished, just remove the id_old field from your new table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO brinkoet_dev.property
  SELECT concat(5, liveprop.ID), field2, field3
  FROM brinkoet_live.property liveprop
  WHERE listing_office='Brink'
```

Where `field2` and `field3` are the rest of the fields of the `liveprop` table (without including the `ID`).

Here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8a2ee/1) for you to play with.

Comment: He says he has 200 fields ;-), it's a lot to type all of them! (see my solution)

Comment: I see. But you're assuming too much. You're assuming that the OP has provileges enough to create and drop columns. That isn't usually the case. In most companies you would have to create a ticket to IT to do that job for you and that would take more time to get resolved than just adding the fields manually. You're also assuming that the only way to get the name of the fields is by manually typing them all. Of course, you can copy paste them in one single operation.

Comment: that's an excellent point MM...in this case i can add fields but i've worked in shops where i can't, so what you are saying is quite valid. thxs for your insight.